# How to create a MySQL database with many tables each with the same field headings?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, field

Probably a silly question, but I'm new to all this.

I am creating a basic quiz program in PHP, I want to have a MySQL database cantoning a table for each quiz, each table needs to have the same headings (Question, 1st 2nd 3rd and 4th multiple choice answer, and correct answer). Each table will then contain how ever many questions are in that particular quiz.

I am using PHPMyAdmin running on WAMP Server.

I am not sure if that's the most efficient way to do it, but I have no other ideas, I'm  very open to suggestions :)

My question is: How can I automatically create more tables within that database with these same headings, so the user can easily create new quizzes.

I am then going to go on to link this with my PHP code, and make a nice user interface for the users to create and do quizzes.

I would be so grateful to any answers, and welcome suggestions. Sorry I made this question quite long. Thanks again in advance :) xx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A far more flexible design would be to have 3 tables;

```
quizzes: overall info about each quiz
    id: int - unique ID of a quiz
    name: text - descriptive text

questions:
    id - int - unique id of question
    quiz_id - int - foreign key pointing at quizzes table
    name: text - text of a question

choices:
    id - int - unique id of a choice/answer for a question
    question_id - int - foreign key pointing at questions table
    name: text - text of this particular choice
```

Which this, you're free to have as many quizzes you want, each having as many questions as it wants, and each question has as many (or few) possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL way is more like creating, say four tables:

- Quizzes(id,name)
- Questions(id,quizz_id,title,answer1,answer2,...,solution)
- Users(id,name,...)
- Quizz_results(id,user_id,quizz_id,result)

For a given quizz, a php script is responsible for pulling the questions for that quizz and another script where you will post users answers will be responsible for calculating the result and feeding the Quizz_result table.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple tables approach suggested by others is "more proper" from the "software design" standpoint, however, it requires you to write far more pretty advanced code.

I'd suggest a simpler structure to get you started, which is much easier to program. Have one single table for all quizzes and have a column "quiz-name" in the each row, like this:

```
 Quiz name | Question      | 1st | 2nd | 3rd   | 4th     | correct
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
 PHP         does it work  | yes | no  | maybe | no idea | 1
 PHP         looks good    | yes | no  | maybe | no idea | 2
 mysql       does it work  | yes | no  | maybe | no idea | 2
 mysql       looks good    | yes | no  | maybe | no idea | 3
```

As you get more proficient, you can revisit your design and use on of the suggested multitable structures.